# unable to copy charts from excel to powerpoint office 2019

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, charts, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2019

Domain user is unable to copy charts created in excel 2019 to powerpoint 2019.

It's possible to insert charts from excel to powerpoint as images via powerpoint context menu but not as editable charts.
When I try to copy the chart via CtrlC, CtrlV or via the context menu (not as image) it loads for like one second and the message "Press the ESC key to cancel this operation" appears in the bottom of powerpoint, but the chart doesn't get copied. There's no error message nor sound indicating something went wrong.

Following things have been tried:

- Tried with existing powerpoint and excel documents, which worked fine on other computers.
- Tried with newly created powerpoint and excel documents.
- Tried running powerpoint and excel in safe mode.
- Uninstalled and newly installed Office 2019 on this computer.

Setup

- Work environment
- Windows 10 Pro (10.0.19042.1165) 64-bit
- Office 2019 MSO (16.0.10377.20023) 64-bit

Thanks in advance

Update:

- Also unable to insert excel charts in MS word.
- Everything works fine with a local user or a different domain user on this computer. (problem seems to be related to this users specific profile)

Comment: Could you copy the Excel chart and paste to Word document? Please create a new local administrator account, then do a test with the new Windows account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added your tests to the original post. I was also able to perform the copy with this users profile on a different computer. But this may be because this user normally works on a notebook, and the roaming profiles on notebooks don't get synchronised to other devices. So I think there's most likely something wrong with this users profile.

Comment: Fastest way would probably be to just delete this users profile and try it with a new one. But as I said, roaming profiles on notebooks aren't sychronised at our place, so this is something I like to avoid if possible.